# The Window is not responding VS Code

Tags: vscode, macos

Al abrir visual me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He hecho con borrarlo y reinstalando, pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, tambien borre a través del terminal pero me sigue mandando el mismo error, aun esperando o reabriendo el programa He borrado cache con ccleaner, desinstalando la aplicación con terminar, utilice los comandos

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
sudo xattr -r -d /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app
codesign --sign - --force --deep /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app
```

y con este comando me aparece el siguiente mensaje
`replacing existing signature`
Pero aun así no consigo abrir la aplicacion

Comment: probaste reiniciando la computadora? a veces queda otra instancia de vs code corriendo en el fondo y falla al tratar de reconectar

Comment: Ya lo hice, pero aparece las ventanas recientes que abrí anteriormente

Comment: borra todos los plugins...